# Pauli matrices in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, dirac-matrices, qft-in-curved-spacetime, clifford-algebra

Just as in a tetrad formalism one brings the gamma matrices from the local Lorentz frame to the manifold through:

$$\gamma^\mu = \gamma^a e^\mu_a.$$

Can one do that for the Pauli spin matrices?

Comment: Since those are just the gamma matrices in 2 and 3 dimensions, yes.

Comment: [See the relation between Pauli Matrices and Gamma Matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices)

Answer (score 2):

In 4D one expands the 3 Pauli matrices $\vec{\sigma}$ to 4 matrices ($I_{2\times 2}$ being the 2x2 identity matrix):

$$ \sigma^a = (I_{2\times 2}, \vec{\sigma})$$

Then you can do the same:

$$\sigma^{\mu} = \sigma^a e^{\mu}_a$$

But $\sigma^\mu$ still carries 2 Weyl-spinor indices (one undotted and one dotted one) as $\gamma^\mu$ carries 2 bispinor indices.

**EDIT**

In Euclidean 3D the 3 Pauli matrices $\vec{\sigma}$ represent the gamma-matrices, so one would have -- as it was already commented by Connor Behan:

$\sigma^i = \sigma^a e^i_a\quad i,a=1,\ldots, 3$